# Keyboard layout wrong

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I tried an English keyboard today and I added the language laybout to Xubuntu. Then I Switched back to the German keyboard and also set the layout settings back to the German language. I even deleted the English layout. Xubuntu is showing `De` as layout but It seems that my keyboard responds as if it was an English one. Rebooting doesn't help. How can I solve this?